# How to declare a default constructor for subclass?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, subclass, default-constructor

Very recently, I have started learning C++ full-time.

It is my understanding that constructors in C++ are not inherited by subclasses, and therefore must be declared in the subclass.

Below, I have a program that has a base class `Car` with a default constructor using default values for the 3 variables, then I have a subclass `SportsCar` that supposedly invokes the default constructor from the base class.

My problem is that I am having trouble figuring out a way to initialize the new variable `acceleration` for the subclass constructor to a value such as `-2`.

Here is my .h file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef CAR_H_
#define CAR_H_

class Car {
public:
    Car();
    void SetName(string carName);
    void SetMPH(int carMPH);
    void SetPrice(double carPrice);

    string GetName() const;
    int GetMPH() const;
    double GetPrice() const;
    virtual void display() {
        cout << "Car Information: " << endl;
        cout << "Model Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Top Speed: " << mph << " miles per hour" << endl;
        cout << "Sales Price: $" << price << endl;
    }

    void SetInfo(string theName, int theMPH, double thePrice) {
        name = theName;
        mph = theMPH;
        price = thePrice;
    }

    virtual ~Car() {
        cout << "deletion complete" << endl;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int mph;
    double price;
};

Car::Car() {
    name = "NoName";
    mph = -1;
    price = 0.0;
}

void Car::SetName(string carName) {
    name = carName;
}

void Car::SetMPH(int carMPH) {
    mph = carMPH;
}

void Car::SetPrice(double carPrice) {
    price = carPrice;
}

string Car::GetName() const {
    return name;
}

int Car::GetMPH() const {
    return mph;
}

double Car::GetPrice() const {
    return price;
}

class SportsCar : public Car {
public:
    void SetAcceleration(double carAcceleration) {
        acceleration = carAcceleration;
    }

    double GetAcceleration() const {
        return acceleration;
    }

    void display() override {
        Car::display();
        cout << "0-60mph Acceleration: " << acceleration << endl;
    }

private:
    double acceleration;
};

#endif /* CAR_H_ */
```

Here is my .cpp file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include "Car.h"

int main() {

    Car* nullCar;
    Car* regularCar1;
    Car* regularCar2;
    SportsCar* nullSportsCar;

    vector<Car*> carsList;
    unsigned int i;

    nullCar = new Car();
    carsList.push_back(nullCar);

    regularCar1 = new Car();
    regularCar1->SetName("2022 Honda Civic");
    regularCar1->SetMPH(140);
    regularCar1->SetPrice(22550.79);
    carsList.push_back(regularCar1);

    regularCar2 = new Car();
    regularCar2->SetInfo("2022 Nissan Altima", 130, 24900.49);
    carsList.push_back(regularCar2);

    nullSportsCar = new SportsCar();
    carsList.push_back(nullSportsCar);

    for (i = 0; i < carsList.size(); i++) {
        carsList.at(i)->display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Car Information: 
Model Name: NoName
Top Speed: -1 miles per hour
Sales Price: $0

Car Information: 
Model Name: 2022 Honda Civic
Top Speed: 140 miles per hour
Sales Price: $22550.8

Car Information: 
Model Name: 2022 Nissan Altima
Top Speed: 130 miles per hour
Sales Price: $24900.5

Car Information: 
Model Name: NoName
Top Speed: -1 miles per hour
Sales Price: $0
0-60mph Acceleration: 0
```

It works fine, but I want the last output `"0-60mph Acceleration"` to read `-2` instead of `0`. I just don't know how to declare a default constructor for the subclass to do that.

Comment: `SportsCar::SportsCar()`? Also, it's better if you read the documentation on constructors.

Comment: ... why doesn't a normal instantiable `Car` have `acceleration`? It seems like a pretty useless `Car` without it.

Comment: *"My problem is that I am having trouble figuring out a way to initialize the new variable `acceleration` for the subclass constructor to a value such as `-2`."* -- what if this was not a subclass? Suppose you had simply defined `class SportsCar { double acceleration; }`. How would you initialize `acceleration` to `-2` in this case? *If you don't know, then ask about the simpler case before adding the complication of inheritance. If you do know, then why not do the same thing in the inheritance case?*

Comment: You might want to review [mre], with emphasis on "minimal". Most of the member functions that you've defined do not come into play until after an object is initialized. Since your question is about initialization, most things that come after initialization can be dropped from your example code. The primary exception is the ability to display the object (so that the initial value can be seen).

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
class SportsCar : public Car {
    public:
        SportsCar()
            : Car()                // Parent Init
               // Preferrer using initializer list for members
               // After Parents come members
            , acceleration(-2)     
        {}
        ....
};
```

Comment: @Jarad Once the code works take it to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)